# How can I get working the script "export photoshop layer to svg" (from HackingUI)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-scripting

I tried this photoshop script from [Hacking UI](http://hackingui.com/design/export-photoshop-layer-to-svg/) and couldn't get it working.

My layer are all named with `.svg` at the end as required. They are all vector content and shapes are closed as required.

I select them all then go to menu ***File > Scripts > Save to svg***.

Then I see a loading icon but nothing happens. No .svg generated, no .ai generated, no message.

I'm using photoshop CS6 (13.0.6 x64) and Illustrator CS6 (16.0.4). Both were running before I tried exporting.

Does anyone know how I could get that script working ?

Thanks

**Update**

I also tried with photoshop CC (2014.0.0 release, 20140508.r.58) and Illustrator CC (2014.0.0 release, 18.0.0) but I was not luckier.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I get that script working ?

Comment: Did your *layer* names end in .svg, as required?

Comment: Yes my layer are all named with ```.svg```at the end.

Comment: Are your layers **vector** content in Photoshop?

Comment: Yes they are vector content and shapes are closed as required.

Comment: Are all layers actually closed vectors? Sometimes they look closed but the points dont actually connect. Also the script doesn't work with text layers only vector shapes

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here: http://hackingui.com/design/my-workflow-to-export-svgs-out-of-my-photoshop-design-files/ Also the script doesn't work on groups of layers, just single vector layers

Answer (score 1):

First off an SVG is a scalable **vector** graphic. If you have a Photoshop layer that uses vector shapes you can use:

> File > Export > "Paths to Illustrator"

this will save your vector paths as an .AI - THEN, you can export from Illustrator to an **svg**. Ideally in the future if you're going to create vector graphics you should start in Illustrator.

Comment: Thanks Eddie. That's the solution I'm using for now but I'd rather skip the Illustrator manual saving step for each file.

Comment: If you are working in Illustrator, is it possible to save all selected layer in different svg files ?

Comment: This script may help you out http://www.tbyrne.org/export-illustrator-layers-to-svg-files

Comment: Well, you can place each layer on a separate artboard (Shift+O for the Artboard Tool) and then File>Save As>SVG and then click 'Use Artboards' and click 'All'. Art boards are good because things can be on different layers and it wont matter as long as they're within the artboard.

Comment: That's exactly what the script here: http://hackingui.com/design/export-photoshop-layer-to-svg/ does. It prevents you from having to manual do the work between photoshop and illustrator